# I need out of stock products to automatically get directed without turning into 404s

Tags: out-of-stock

Would this work?

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RedirectOutOfStockProductObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        if ($product->getIsInStock() === false) {
            $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
            $categoryId = $categoryIds[0];

            $redirectUrl = $this->_productRepository->getById($product->getId())->getUrlInStore(['_query' => ['SID' => '', '___store' => $product->getStoreId()]]);
```

Comment: share events.xml code as well.
Also mension which issues facing with the above code.